# Weird node number in load balancer setup

Tags: cluster, pacemaker, corosync, digital-ocean

I got an odd problem here. I set up Corosync and Pacemaker, I used this guide as a reference but I improvised a little the first time installing it since I'm doing this to learn, not following instructions like a slave. But as I got this odd error, I booted up a new VPS to try again, this time following the instructions like a slave.

Here is the guide I followed, pretty nice set up from Mitchell Anicas over at Digital Ocean: [How To Create a High Availability HAProxy Setup with Corosync, Pacemaker, and Floating IPs on Ubuntu 14.04 | digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-high-availability-haproxy-setup-with-corosync-pacemaker-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04)

The errors I have been getting is related to the number of nodes in the cluster. In my settings, I have specified explicitly to do two-node cluster.

**OS: Ubuntu Xenial Xursus (16.04.4)**

```
totem {
  version: 2
  cluster_name: lbcluster
  transport: udpu
  interface {
    ringnumber: 0
    bindnetaddr: primary's-privateIP
    broadcast: yes
    mcastport: 5405
  }
}

quorum {
  provider: corosync_votequorum
  two_node: 1
}

nodelist {
  node {
    ring0_addr: primary's-privateIP
    name: primary
    nodeid: 1
  }
  node {
    ring0_addr: secondary's-privateIP
    name: secondary
    nodeid: 2
  }
}

logging {
  to_logfile: yes
  logfile: /var/log/corosync/corosync.log
  to_syslog: yes
  timestamp: on
}
```

If I run `sudo crm status`, the output I get looks like this.

```
Last updated: Fri Apr 13 15:31:47 2018          Last change: Fri Apr 13 14:08:42 2018 by root via cibadmin on secondary<br>
Stack: corosync<br>
Current DC: secondary (version 1.1.14-70404b0) - partition with quorum<br>
3 nodes and 0 resources configured

Online: [ primary secondary ]
OFFLINE: [ sh-ps-02 ]
```

I also run `sudo crm configure show` to show the configuration:

```
node 1: primary<br>
node 2: secondary<br>
node 2130706433: sh-ps-02<br>
property cib-bootstrap-options: \<br>
have-watchdog=false \<br>
dc-version=1.1.14-70404b0 \<br>
cluster-infrastructure=corosync \<br>
cluster-name=debian \<br>
stonith-enabled=false \<br>
no-quorum-policy=ignore
```

**Why is there a weird looking node, with the node name of the secondary node running, but offline even if it's explicitly said that it's a two-node cluster?**

Addition 16. April 2018:
I ran `sudo corosync-cmapctl | grep members` to get the members of the cluster, and there is no traces of that weird cluster member that is offline.

```
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1.config_version (u64) = 0
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1.ip (str) = r(0) ip(x.x.82.204)
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1.join_count (u32) = 3
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1.status (str) = joined
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.2.config_version (u64) = 0
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.2.ip (str) = r(0) ip(x.x.82.167)
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.2.join_count (u32) = 1
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.2.status (str) = joined
```

Comment: It's not corosync related. You mistake corosync for pacemaker.

Comment: It is corosync that I'm configuring. Most config is at the corosync software, not the pacemaker. The config that dictates if its two-node or not is located at etc/corosync/corosync.conf. Furthermore, I don't see where in my message I point out whether I'm thinking corosync or pacemaker. I'm asking generally not pointing out a specific software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Xenial is shipping Corosync and Pacemaker started and enabled in systemd, with a `corosync.conf` configuration that would bring up a "single node cluster". That entry, is likely the hostname of one of your nodes that was added prior to you setting the names: `primary` and `secondary`.

To clean it up, simply delete that entry:

```
# crm node delete sh-ps-02
```

Side note: naming your nodes `primary` and `secondary` isn't a great practice. `node-a` and `node-b` would be better, since either node in the cluster should be able to act as "primary" or "secondary".

Comment: Thank you for this suggestions, primary and secondary was the default naming, and I will change it to something more identifiable when I'm done and enter testing stage! 

I will test your suggestions now, and report back what I find! :)

Edit: Thank you very much, this worked out perfectly and I've added this to my notes! +++ For good help! :3